# Basic difference between .net 3.5 and 4.0

Tags: .net, comparison

Please tell me the basic difference between dotnet 2008 and 2010(3.5 and 4.0)

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio or .NET Framework ?

Comment: That would be 2 and 0.5 respectively.

Comment: @Nifle: Actually -2 and -0.5 :P but I had a pretty good laugh :D

Answer (score 12):

MSDN has a number of "What's New" pages up, including:

- "[What's New in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb386063(VS.100).aspx)"
- "[What's New in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd409230(VS.100).aspx)"

Answer (score 7):

Uh, where to start. Here is what I love:

- all new things about parallel computing
- "dynamic" keyword and Dynamic Language Routine
- code contracts
- new background garbage collector
- compiling only necessary parts of Primary Interop Assemblies into your application, and compatibility/versioning improvements that this infrastructure allows for pure .NET code
- new stuff about exception handling (look for corrupted state exceptions)
- small stuff like BigInteger and SortedSet classes
- memory-mapped files handling in managed code

and may others, look around on the net, there is a lot of information already.

Answer (score 7):

I hope I'm not incorrectly reading jignesh's question, but I would have to assume that the linking of a ton of "What's New" pages is probably not what they wanted. I would think that they could have done a search and pulled up that much.

I think what they are looking for is more of a feel for what people can break down for them as a reason to or not to go with a particular version - personal experience, not press releases.

For me, I'd say the biggest things for me that make 2010/4.0 worth the trip are the changes that allow me to distribute a client application without needing the dnFx installed on a machine, the new GC, the crazy-cool "dynamic", and (sadly, yes) the multi-monitor support.

Answer (score 3):

A simple google brings up...

http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2009/05/22/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-beta-1-justin-van-patten.aspx

There are probably a lot more things, the Framework is massive so changes which are interesting for person x might not be as important for person y.

Answer (score 2):

built in MVC in visual studio 2010 !!!

Answer (score 0):

In that case (lance may) I must say that my favorites are the dynamic also and the super great solution to multi-threading - the Parallel lib, its really awesome and fast! (nested parallels are not always faster BTW)

But I feel that @jignesh asked if there's a real difference in the engineering structure, how it works from behind, something someone from inside should say, after all decided that it's different enough that if you want 3.5 and 4 in the same machine you need to install them both.

Anyway I would love an answer to that if there is :)

Answer (score -4):

Difference between `Framework 3.5` and `Framework 4.0`:

1. `EnableViewState - [true or false]`  in `Framework 3.5`

   `EnableViewState -[Enabled/Disabled/Inherits]` in `Framework 4.0`
2. `Keyword` and `Description` is added in `Framework 4.0` while it is not available in `Framework 3.5` in the Page Directives.